# how to use multiple table in python sqlitedict in the same file?

Tags: python, sqlite, persistent-storage

In sqlitedict README on github, it says that one of the features is:

> Support for multiple tables (=dicts) living in the same database file.

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/sqlitedict#features

How can I do that? I have researched but all were workarounds, e.g. nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code it shows that the class takes `tablename` as an argument. So, the answer is to use that argument. Kinda simple but wasn't available in the docs.

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/sqlitedict/blob/master/sqlitedict.py#L108